The Specified deps.json Does Not Exist... Even Though It Does
Visual Studio 2022 (17.11.6)
.Net 8.0
I have a project where I currently need to update my model after I added a field to the DB.  I run the following scaffolding command using the Package Manager Console:
Scaffold-DbContext 'Name=ConnectionStrings:'Entities' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force -Context EntityContext
It successfully builds the project, but then throws the following error:
The specified deps.json [\\SomeServer\ThisProject\bin\Debug\net8.0\ThisProject.deps.json] does not exist
However, if I copy that exact folder path (except the leading two escape slashes) and paste it into Windows Explorer, it brings me to that folder and the file "ThisProject.deps.json" is in there.
I have tried deleting the "obj" and "bin" and ".vs" folders.  No change.  I have tried deleting the "ThisProject.deps.json" file itself.  It just gets recreated every time I build the project.  I have tried updated Visual Studio. No change.  I have tried updated all my Entity Framework packages.  No change.  I have tried setting this as the default project (there is only one project in this solution so I don't see how that would matter anyway).  No change.
I will note that where I work requires me to run this project as admin.

I found you are using \\SomeServer, it should be a problem caused by the network path. Could you create a sample  and verify it in local, thanks.

Hi Ross, after checking a lot of github issues, I found it's a know issue for network path, and I will summarize all the details below, hope it can help others who will face the same issue in the future.

That's odd since it has never been a problem before.  I always run my projects across the network, never locally.  We have other developers here doing the same thing and they aren't experiencing this problem.

Use Scaffold-dbcontext and Add-Migration command, it will show the error message The specified deps.json [\\SomeServer\ThisProject\bin\Debug\net8.0\ThisProject.deps.json] does not exist if we are executing from a network drive that begins with two slashes. i.e. "\SomeServer...".
And it is working perfectly on local drive.
Related Links
The specified deps.json [\\TeamDrive\IT\Team Software\Project\etc...] does not exist#14349
deps.json not found due to extra backslashes being added to search path for a network drive beginning with '\' #21048

Moving the project to a local folder fixed it.  Though, it doesn't answer why this is a problem at all, nor why it just suddenly started happening, and why it isn't happening to any other developers.  Thank you for your help.  I have been needing to get past this for a week now.
